# What is a minimal relation?

Tags: relations

I was reading [this definition of transitive closure of a relation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transitive_closure), where is written that the transitive closure is *minimal*:

> the transitive closure of a binary relation R on a set X is the transitive relation R+ on set X such that R+ contains R and R+ is minimal (Lidl and Pilz 1998:337).

I couldn't find any definition of a *minimal relation* on the web. When is a relation *minimal*?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Minimal" does not really mean something by itself.

What we *can* speak of is a minimal thing with such-and-such property, which means a thing that (a) has such-and-such property, but (b) no smaller thing has such-and-such property.

Concretely, in a definition such as

> If $R$ is a relation, then its *transitive closure* $R^+$ means the minimal transitive relation that contains $R$.

what it says is that

1. $R^+$ is a transitive relation that contains $R$ as a subset, and
2. There is no proper subset of $R^+$ that is both transitive and contains $R$.

A definition of this form secretly implies a claim that there is exactly one $R^+$ that satisfies those two conditions. In general this needs to be proved. In the present case one can easily see that we can find $R^+$ as the *intersection* of all subsets of $X\times X$ that are transitive and contain $R$.

Comment: Thanks, i quoted the full sentence in the question

Comment: @danza: I went ahead and guessed anyway -- it's close enough that I think my explanation fits the one you quote too.

Comment: Yep! I will wait a few minutes and then mark your answer. Thanks!